# Does row_number() affect the output of the sql query?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have an original query given as, which selects extra columns in the select statement:

```
 SELECT ARN,FDDATE as carded_date,PRODUCT_CODE as variant
  from (
               Select *,row_number() over(partition by ARN order by FDDATE desc) as rnk 
        FROM (
                SELECT
                    *,
                    case when FINAL_DECISION_DATE != 'nan' then cast(to_date(FINAL_DECISION_DATE,"yyyy-MM-dd") as DATE) 
                    end as FDDATE
            FROM
                hdfc_dre
            WHERE FINAL_DECISION_DATE != 'nan' and cast(to_date(FINAL_DECISION_DATE,"yyyy-MM-dd") as DATE) <= "2022-10-31"
            UNION ALL
          SELECT
                Curable_or_Non_Curable,FINAL_DECISION,
                APPLICATION_REFERENCE_NUMBER AS ARN,CAST(WORKITEMID as int),PRODUCT_CODE,DROPOFF_REASON, cast(cast(to_date(FINAL_DECISION_DATE_TIME,"yyyy-MM-dd") as date) as String),
                CUSTOMER_TYPE,APPLICATION_TYPE,CAST(CREATION_DATE_TIME as STRING),SOURCING_CHANNEL,
                case
                when substr(FINAL_DECISION_DATE_TIME, 3, 1) = '-' then cast(to_date(substr(FINAL_DECISION_DATE_TIME, 0, 9), "dd-MMM-yy") as DATE) 
                when substr(FINAL_DECISION_DATE_TIME, 3, 1) = '/' then cast(to_date(substr(FINAL_DECISION_DATE_TIME, 0, 9), "MM/dd/yy") as Date) 


                end as FDDATE
            FROM
                HDFC_TABLE
  )
  )
  WHERE rnk = 1
  AND FINAL_DECISION in ('APPROVE')
  ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

I removed the unnecessary select statements and ran the inner queries separately before union and the output matched that of the above but when i completed the query as:

```
 SELECT ARN,FDDATE as carded_date,PRODUCT_CODE as variant
  from (
               Select *,row_number() over(partition by ARN order by FDDATE desc) as rnk 
        FROM (
                SELECT
                   FINAL_DECISION,
                   ARN,
                   PRODUCT_CODE,
                    case when FINAL_DECISION_DATE != 'nan' then cast(to_date(FINAL_DECISION_DATE,"yyyy-MM-dd") as DATE)
                    end as FDDATE
            FROM
                hdfc_dre
            WHERE FINAL_DECISION_DATE != 'nan' and cast(to_date(FINAL_DECISION_DATE,"yyyy-MM-dd") as DATE) <= "2022-10-31"
            UNION ALL
          SELECT
                FINAL_DECISION,
                APPLICATION_REFERENCE_NUMBER AS ARN,PRODUCT_CODE,
                case
                when substr(FINAL_DECISION_DATE_TIME, 3, 1) = '-' then cast(to_date(substr(FINAL_DECISION_DATE_TIME, 0, 9), "dd-MMM-yy") as DATE) 
                when substr(FINAL_DECISION_DATE_TIME, 3, 1) = '/' then cast(to_date(substr(FINAL_DECISION_DATE_TIME, 0, 9), "MM/dd/yy") as Date) 


                end as FDDATE
            FROM
                HDFC_TABLE
                  )
   )                 
  WHERE rnk = 1
  AND FINAL_DECISION in ('APPROVE')
  ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

The output changes. Can someone please explain what is the difference!?

```
bookings_op.where(col("FDDATE").isNotNull).select(count(col("ARN"))).show()
bookings_or.where(col("FDDATE").isNotNull).select(count(col("ARN"))).show()
+----------+
|count(ARN)|
+----------+
|    394918|
+----------+

+----------+
|count(ARN)|
+----------+
|    159050|
+----------+
```

Comment: Can you highlight the differences between the two requests. It is quite difficult to see them. If it is just a matter of columns in select statement, I would say there is no reason to have different outputs.

Comment: it is only the select statements that have changed, instead of select * ive selected only a few of them and removed the rest unused values.

Comment: If you run all the SELECT statements individually then do the corresponding statements produce the same number of rows?

Comment: `bookings_op` and `bookings_or` are clearly two different objects.  How were they created?  You're not showing us enough here.

Comment: Please check whether the third column that you get with `SELECT *, ... FROM hdfc_dre` is really the ARN column. A mismatch there is the only explanation that I have been able to conjure so far.